# Linux /home directory full on 500 GB drive

Tags: partitioning, linux-mint

I am a new Linux user trying to install the programs I will be using, such as Anaconda and QGIS. I created a 500GB partition in my 2TB external hard drive (Mac_Storage) to boot Linux Mint from. I started installing Anaconda and it failed because I ran out of empty space to put it, even though it is my first program to install. I looked into what my problem was, and I do not have something mounted where it should be, but I am not sure how to fix it.

The output of `df -h` is as follows:

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev            1.9G  4.0K  1.9G   1% /dev
tmpfs           385M  1.4M  383M   1% /run
/dev/sdb2       500G  8.0G  493G   2% /isodevice
/dev/loop0      1.9G  1.9G     0 100% /cdrom
/dev/loop1      1.9G  1.9G     0 100% /rofs
/cow            1.9G  1.9G   31M  99% /
tmpfs           1.9G   92M  1.8G   5% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M  4.0K  5.0M   1% /run/lock
tmpfs           1.9G     0  1.9G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
tmpfs           1.9G  4.0K  1.9G   1% /tmp
tmpfs           385M   48K  385M   1% /run/user/999
/dev/sdb1       1.4T   98G  1.3T   8% /media/mint/Mac_Storage
/dev/sda3       465G   60G  405G  13% /media/mint/OS
```

Also, the output of `lsblk` is as follows:

```
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
loop0    7:0    0   1.9G  0 loop /cdrom
loop1    7:1    0   1.8G  1 loop /rofs
sda      8:0    0 465.8G  0 disk 
├─sda1   8:1    0   499M  0 part 
├─sda2   8:2    0   128M  0 part 
├─sda3   8:3    0 464.7G  0 part /media/mint/OS
└─sda4   8:4    0   515M  0 part 
sdb      8:16   0   1.8T  0 disk 
├─sdb1   8:17   0   1.3T  0 part /media/mint/Mac_Storage
└─sdb2   8:18   0   500G  0 part /isodevice
sr0     11:0    1   3.1G  0 rom
```

As a new Linux user, this is all in Greek to me at this point, so I do not know how to utilize all of the empty space in /isodevice for installing programs. The directory /media/mint/Mac_Storage is off limits for downloading and installing programs, as that is where I store my files and data. /media/mint/OS is the hard drive on the computer where Windows 10 is still installed.

Comment: _lsblk | grep -v "loop"  && df -h | grep -v "loop" | grep -v "tempfs"_ shows what's going on a little better, but for now, ignore everything which isn't in sda and sdb . Did you choose the standard ext4 partition or btrfs when Mint was installed?

Comment: I don't recall getting an option like that. After I created the partition on my drive, I copied the image file to that partition and used YUMI to "install" a multiboot into the same partition. That is the last partition related option that I recall. Can I mount the /home directory into /isodevice?

Comment: Using YUMI to "install" a multiboot into the same partition is not the standard, recommended method. Please see https://linuxmint-installation-guide.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html

Comment: Thanks, I will look into this new method.

Comment: I realized that a Live version of Linux was not what I wanted. I set up a Dual Boot, and am no longer having the issues of running out of space in my partitions. Thank you for you assistance in this matter.